# Groovy + Insight (Jira) Exception on split method

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm trying to create a script with Groovy to be able to auto affect a Jira issue to a specific object in Insight (Add-on of Jira).

Actually, I need to split a value. The value is "2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)", I want to have AFAW16-FS01.francois.int part only. I can do it if I apply directly the method to the text but it's not working with a string.

Here is my code :

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.CommentBean;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeBean
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean
 
  
Class objectFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade");
def objectFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectFacadeClass);
  
Class iqlFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.IQLFacade");
def iqlFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(iqlFacadeClass);
  
def objects = iqlFacade.findObjectsByIQLAndSchema(10,"objectTypeId = 2443");
//def test = "AF-172738"
//def ObjectInsightBean = objectFacade.loadObjectBean(test)
//log.warn("ObjectInsightBean " + ObjectInsightBean)
def n = 0
(objects).each {
    CurrentObject = objects[n]
    def FQDNValue = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(CurrentObject.getId(),47464).getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0]; //Load Attribute Value
    //log.warn("Server " + objects[n])
    //log.warn("FQDNValue " + FQDNValue)
    //FQDNValueSTR = FQDNValue.ToString()
    log.warn("FQDNValue brut" + FQDNValue)   
    def values = '2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)'.split("\\("); //WORKS !
    def FQDNSplit = FQDNValue.split("\\("); // NOT WORKS

    
    def Value1 = values[1]
    def Value2 = Value1.substring(0, Value1.length() - 1);
    
    //log.warn("Values " + Value2)
    //result = (issue.getSummary()) //Show subject
      
    //log.warn("result " + result)
    n ++
      
}
```

FQDNSplit  contain "2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)" but i have the following error:

```
class com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.common.exception.GroovyInsightException

GroovyInsightException: No signature of method: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeValueBean.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [\(] Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long), getAt(java.lang.String), print(java.lang.Object), sprintf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'
```

Any idea? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple comman extracts the substring that you want:

```
String res = '2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)'.replaceFirst( /\d\(([^\(\)]+)\)/, '$1' )
assert res == 'AFAW16-FS01.francois.int'
```

Also you should stick with Java Naming Conventions, and DO NOT name variables starting with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use String operations on something that isn't a string. If you convert the value into a String then this code will work:

```
FQDNValue.replaceAll(/.*\((.*)\)/,'$1')
```

You need a method to get the string value.

e.g.

```
FQDNValue.getTextValue().replaceAll(/.*\((.*)\)/,'$1')
```

Your updated code might look like this:

```
  def FQDNValue =
    objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean( 
      CurrentObject.getId(),47464
    ).getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0].getTextValue() 

  assert FQDNValue == '2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)'

  println "old: $FQDNValue"
  def newValue = FQDNValue.replaceAll(/.*\((.*)\)/,'$1')
  println "new: $newValue"
```

With this output:

```
old: 2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)
new: AFAW16-FS01.francois.int
```

This should work as [ObjectAttributeValueBean](https://insight-javadoc.riada.io/insight-javadoc-5.0/com/riadalabs/jira/plugins/insight/services/model/ObjectAttributeValueBean.html) has a [getTextValue](https://insight-javadoc.riada.io/insight-javadoc-5.0/com/riadalabs/jira/plugins/insight/services/model/ObjectAttributeValueBean.html#getTextValue--) method.

#### Use getTextValue

[ObjectAttributeValueBean](https://insight-javadoc.riada.io/insight-javadoc-5.0/com/riadalabs/jira/plugins/insight/services/model/ObjectAttributeValueBean.html) has a [getTextValue](https://insight-javadoc.riada.io/insight-javadoc-5.0/com/riadalabs/jira/plugins/insight/services/model/ObjectAttributeValueBean.html#getTextValue--) method, that returns a String:

```
public String getTextValue()
```

Comment: I added string fqdnstring = fqdnvalue;
and still have error:
class com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.common.exception.GroovyInsightException

GroovyInsightException: No signature of method: Script1.string() is applicable for argument types: (com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeValueBean) values: [[2629351(AFAW16-FS01.francois.int)]] Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), run()'

Comment: If you put it in double quotes, as in my example, it should work. Alternatively use the `toString()` method, as suggested in the error message. I used quotes because it was easier to type.

Comment: I added your trick  
"$FQDNValue".replaceAll(/.*\((.*)\)/,'$1')
def FQDNSplit = FQDNValue.split("\\("); // NOT WORKS

Same error... :(

Comment: That's odd. I'll update my answer with more details. I notice you're logging the FQDNValue, what gets wriiten to the log?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe an easy way to convert FQDNValue to string?

I don't found the good method on Google. Seems working with class but i don't understand the good way.

Answer (score 0):

i'm go on in the script and found the good solution for the split. Here what i using (i renamed string to have a better understanding)

To convert to string i simply do it (haha)

```
def fqdn_string = fqdnvalue.toString()
```

Now i'm blocked to the last part of the code :( maybe you can understand why i can't update the issue

```
    import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField

import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.CommentBean;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeBean
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean
import groovy.transform.ToString
  
Class objectFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade");
def objectFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectFacadeClass);

//CustomField jiraCustomField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(12124);
CustomField valueCF = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(12124);  
CustomField insightCF = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(12124);


Class iqlFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.IQLFacade");
def iqlFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(iqlFacadeClass);
  
def objects = iqlFacade.findObjectsByIQLAndSchema(10,"objectTypeId = 2443");
//def test = "AF-172738"
//def ObjectInsightBean = objectFacade.loadObjectBean(test)
//log.warn("ObjectInsightBean " + ObjectInsightBean)
def n = 0
(objects).each {
    CurrentObject = objects[n]
    def fqdnvalue = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(CurrentObject.getId(),47464).getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0]; //Load Attribute Value

    
   
    def fqdn_string = fqdnvalue.toString()
    def fqdn_string_split = fqdn_string.split("\\("); 
    def fqdn_string_split_1 = fqdn_string_split[1]
    def fqdn_string_split_2 = fqdn_string_split_1.substring(0, fqdn_string_split_1.length() - 2);
    
    result = (issue.getSummary().contains(fqdn_string_split_2)) // if the value fqdn_string_split_2 present in the summary => result = true
    if (result==true){
        log.info("Statement " + "True" + CurrentObject);
        MutableIssue mi = (MutableIssue) issue;
        mi.setCustomFieldValue(insightCF, objects[n]); // => Work if i replace objects[n] by objects
        ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().updateIssue(currentUser, mi, EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false); // Error  GroovyInsightException: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean cannot be cast to java.util.Collection'
        }
    log.info("fqdn_string_split_2 " + fqdn_string_split_2)
    log.info("Result " + result)
    n ++
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parts through existing methods

```
def FQDNValue = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(CurrentObject.getId(),47464).getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0]; //Load Attribute Value

def id = FQDNValue.getId(); // "2629351"
def value = FQDNValue.getValue(); // "AFAW16-FS01.francois.int"
```